# Excel: Summing noncontiguous array via indirect + address

Tags: arrays, excel, match

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROWS(ADF$1:ADF1642),MATCH(sheet2!$C$25:$C$29,sheet1!1:1,0)))
```

That formula returns {"$AFX$1642";"$AJR$1642";"$AKF$1642";"$AJD$1642";"$AIP$1642"} without the Indirect, and the values in those cells with the Indirect prefix.  I need to sum them all, but it only returns the first:  $AFX$1642.

There are indeed similar topics, but their solutions do not include the lookup nature of matching an array from sheet 2, to the array in sheet 1 that has a multitude of columns to quote, unquote, "exclude".

Halp!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not particularly fond of your current set-up, I have to say (a worksheet which references up to column AIP?!), nor of the current formula you are using (there is almost always a better alternative to constructions using INDIRECT/ADDRESS). However, without knowing precisely what you are trying to achieve, and not being able to see an actual workbook, it's difficult to suggest improvements.

The coercion you require with your current construction is:

=SUMPRODUCT(N(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROWS(ADF$1:ADF1642),MATCH(Sheet2!$C$25:$C$29,Sheet1!1:1,0)))))

Regards